# Filtering out VLAN tagged packets on Linux bridge

Tags: linux, iptables, bridge, vlan, ebtables

I have the following IF configuration:

```
eth0 --- br0 --- eth1
```

I receive udp broadcast transmission (on port 20000) on eth1 and do not want the bridge to forward it to eth0 (my wired interface). Hence, I apply

```
ebtables -t filter -A FORWARD -o eth0 -p 0x0800 --ip-protocol udp --ip-destination-port 20000 -j DROP
```

That works great for me. When I am running my device in VLAN mode, i.e. with the following configuration,

```
eth0 --- br0 --- eth1 
          |
       br0.100
```

here I have added a VLAN-enabled bridge to manage radio on VLAN 100. The traffic arrives tagged on eth1 and I am unable to detect it using the same rule when it goes through the bridge.

Tried to detect the packets with iptables and ebtables with its vlan options. Were not able to filter them by udp port via ebtables. Moreover, could not find the method to mark them by port via iptables. Also, tried marking using physdev without success.

Is there a right method to do this for a tagged stream?

Comment: This is a good question (and an interesting one!) but it's off-topic for stackoverflow (which is for software development question).  This would be a good candidate for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to see 802.1Q encapsulated bridged packets
with iptables by default.

To enable this, do:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
```

See http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html

Now, you can filter those packets with iptables. You should
find out how to match the destination port in the packet with
something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m u32 --u32 "W&0xFFFF=0x4E20" -j DROP
```

where 0x4E20 is your port (20000) and W is the offset of
your 4 byte match (note that you are matching only last two
bytes with 0x0000FFFF). You have to find out what the W is.

See iptables man page for details on u32 match.